# Magento 2: Is it possible to have two stores with different views and same login for customers?

Tags: magento2, multistore, login

I'm trying to create two store with different views and same login for customers. I read about configuring multiple stores with same backend admin panel. And I would like to create the same logins for two store for users(customers). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration -> Account Sharing Options
```

Set `Share Customer Accounts` to `Global`.

`Global` means `Shares customer account information with every website and store in the Magento installation`.

Reference Links:

- https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/customers/customer-configuration.html
- https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/account-scope.html